# Error with **args and *kwargs

Tags: python, arguments

I'm learning *args and **kwargs and had a question. What happens when we instead use ** on a list and * on a dictionary? I know it doesn't work but was wondering if it's a syntax issue or if there's something going on that has a more intuitive explanation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's find out:

```
>>> def f(arg):
...   print(arg)
... 
>>> f(**[])
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: f() argument after ** must be a mapping, not list
>>> f(*{})
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: f() missing 1 required positional argument: 'arg'
>>> f(*{'foo': 42})
foo
```

So the list fails because the type is completely wrong, and the dict passes the keys, as expected:

```
>>> list({'foo': 42})
['foo']
```